# ¿Cómo cambiar color de un tema en netBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, color

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería saber cómo cambiar el color de esa lista que te muestra todos los métodos. Al usar un tema oscuro, queda feo que el nombre del método te lo marque en NEGRO, quisiera cambiarlo a otro color como blanco o algo de eso, ¿cómo se hace?

---

Sí, pero ¿sabes cual de todas esas opciones es para cambiar eso que dije? he estado fijándome pero no la encuentro

Comment: Hola ¿Que tema tienes configurado?

Comment: Tools->Options y allí deberías encontrar una opción que diga **Font** and **Colors** o algo por el estilo. Fíjate que de https://netbeansthemes.com/ puedes sacar varios temas muy buenos, creados por los usuarios.

Comment: Hola, el tema que tengo es Dracula